# How to make a gold ore texture?

Tags: materials

I am trying to make a gold ore material on my object but I cannot seem to make it look right with different nodes. Can anybody help me?!! I am just learning about nodes so I am fairly new to how they work and it needs to be explained in detail what to do.
This is what I have that is slightly close to what I am looking for...
[image]

Comment: you can use the search box at the top of the page to look for similar questions like these: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold+material

Answer (score -3):

You need more roughness, your model is too smooth. Try with the Principled shader which is a new node in Blender 2.79 +

Comment: To make the answer useful, please add detail on **how** the Principled shader should be used.

Comment: I have tried the Principled shader and it did not help.